# How do I distract the receptionist in Tidy Park?

Tags: golf-story

While investigating Jerome's disappearance in the Tidy Park clubhouse, Lara asks you to distract the manor's receptionist so you can grab a laundry token out of her cash register.

I've tried talking to the lady multiple times, but I can't seem to get her attention.

[image]

How do I distract the receptionist in Tidy Park's manor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the ring bell from the soda bar room and replace the non-working bell at the receptionist's desk with it

Comment: Just to add as well: the broken bell to replace is on the north side of that desk.  It might be easy to miss if you didn't notice the bell you picked up from the 'soda' bar.